# How to stop woocommerce from adding tax

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, tax

commerce rest API to create orders, is there a way to send order amount inclusive of tax. i do not want woocomm to add tax to the order if the order amount is inclusive of tax, i have already tried sending "prices_include_tax" in the payload but still the tax gets added

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to make the tax_class='zero-rate' in the line item of the payload, Hope it will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).